# AngularJS HelloWorld not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to make my AngularJS HelloWorld work but I can't. My code is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html np-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
        app.controller("appCtrl",function($scope){
            $scope.mensagem="HelloWorld!";
        });
        console.log(angular);
        console.log(app);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="appCtrl">
        {{mensagem}}
    </div>
</body>
```

The output:

```
{{mensagem}}
```

I searched about similar questions here in SO but found only questions with a missing `ng-app` atribute.
I tried opening my file both in Firefox and Chrome and I get the same error. Logging both `angular` and `app` reveal that they are both defined.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML tag, you've misspelled `ng-app`, which is probably the main reason it's not working. You should also place the include for Angular down at the end of the body, which ensures the app and controller elements are defined before the script runs:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="appCtrl">
        {{mensagem}}
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
        app.controller("appCtrl",function($scope){
            $scope.mensagem="HelloWorld!";
        });
        console.log(angular);
        console.log(app);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If only you knew how long I have been looking at this code... It was indeed the `np-app` that screwed me. I am very ashamed. Thank you.